# How can I extract tabular values from a HTML source in Qt?

Tags: html, excel, qt, csv

I am trying to create an app which extracts financial data from any arbitrary page regardless of the financial statement format or conventions. So basically I want to parse or extract a field/value and write the same field into a CSV or Excel file on a Desktop. The following quote illustrates what I want to do;

> Parse(each HTML line) --> value --> Write(file.csv,value)

In the above process, I completely comfortable about writing to a CSV or Excel file; my problem is the parsing of HTML code part.

Obviously, I could scan the HTML page for table syntaxes and then extract values; but I am afraid this will prove futile for web pages with multiple tabs in them. Because each tab may load different numerical values, for example, a financial website may have 2 tabs for annual and quarter reports. I have no experience with HTML, but I am willing to learn and get around this problem. But before I proceed I want to if there is any straight forward or smarter way of doing this in Qt? I don't want to reinvent the wheel here. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:
1. QRegExp (old class) or QRegularExpression for match simple pattern. But you must learn regular expression syntax. I recommend learn it For example you can bulid expresion for match pattern like: Data name: numers (lik 4354.65 etc).  this is universal programing solution in much language.
2. QDomDocument class provide nice interface to parse ml (html, xml) documents with tree value. QDomDocument is slow, use mutch memory but you can get value from specific tags-tree. It is complicated.

Tabs isn't problem when page is reload. Simple html page need set to you ALL tabs. Only when tabs is link or use AJAX you need physical "click" to tab for get new data. You must download two html pages for parse.
Some good pages allow you site map. Try parse it for get interesting addresses.

Comment: Thanks bro :) I will try your advice. Cheers.